# Is freetds version 1.1.4 compatible with Microsoft SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, freetds

We are planning to use freetds 1.1.4 in our organisation to connect to SQL Server 2017 using Perl and C++.

We saw a compatiblity chart but it doesn't have any info for SQL Server 2017. Could you please let us know whether we can use 1.1.4 for Microsoft SQL Server 2017. Please do reply

Below is the link for same
https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html

Comment: Looks like it [does work](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/146) and that the documentation has just not been updated in (what appears to be) literally years.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, and apologies that the documentation is out of date. Microsoft is very good about maintaining backwards compatibility. I would recommend using TDS Version 7.4, if possible:

https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html

Good luck!